# Disable ssl on subdomains

Tags: wordpress, https

I have a main domain where I added a private SSL. I also use cloudflare protection with their ssl, full strict, but I added a new subdomain in where I don't want ssl enabled. It seems to be the case even if I didn't add anything.

So please can someone tell me how to disable ssl on my new subdomain in which i installed wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you have an SSL certificate, you don't *have* to use it.  By using `http://` instead of `https://` you will not be using SSL.

If you want to force people to not use SSL you can add the following to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But be aware, non SSL sites are now being marked insecure by browsers and also there appears to be a search engine ranking penalty.

Comment: hello and thank you @steve for your answer ,,, i tried using http:// but it redirects to https:// instead ,,, and adding your code to my .htaccess file of my subdirectory worked like a charm ;;;; thank you very much for your help

Comment: plz if my subdomain has a bad search engine ranking and bad reputation on them ,, will it apply also to my primary domain ,,, thanks

Comment: You are better asking that as a separate question...but I am almost certain it is one someone will have asked before.